# Making a pandas dataframe from a .npy file

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, pickle

I'm trying to make a pandas dataframe from a .npy file which, when read in using np.load, returns a numpy array containing a dictionary. My initial instinct was to extract the dictionary and then create a dataframe using pd.from_dict, but this fails every time because I can't seem to get the dictionary out of the array returned from np.load. It looks like it's just np.array([dictionary, dtype=object]), but I can't get the dictionary by indexing the array or anything like that. I've also tried using np.load('filename').item() but the result still isn't recognized by pandas as a dictionary.

Alternatively, I tried pd.read_pickle and that didn't work either.

How can I get this .npy dictionary into my dataframe? Here's the code that keeps failing...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

targetdir = '../test_dir/'

filenames = []
successful = []
unsuccessful = []
for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk(targetdir):
    for name in files:
        filenames.append(name)
        path_to_use = os.path.join(dirs, name)
        if path_to_use.endswith('.npy'):
            try:
                file_dict = np.load(path_to_use).item()
                df = pd.from_dict(file_dict)
                #df = pd.read_pickle(path_to_use)
                successful.append(path_to_use)
            except:
                unsuccessful.append(path_to_use)
                continue

print str(len(successful)) + " files were loaded successfully!"
print "The following files were not loaded:"
for item in unsuccessful:
    print item + "\n"

print df
```

Comment: How did you create the `.npy` file? is it using `np.save()`

Comment: It was just given to me, unfortunately. I was told that I could get what I needed from it using np.load.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `pd.DataFrame.from_dict` instead of `pd.from_dict`? At least in `pandas 0.18.1` the latter doesn't exist. Either way, are you sure the problem is with the `.npy` file? I can successfully save and load dictionaries with `np.save` and `np.load`. Could you post details about `file_dict` as well as the error messages?

Comment: You're right about pd.DataFrame.from_dict()! However, when I give that the argument x where x = np.load(path_to_use).item(), I get an error that says "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional". [Here's](http://imgur.com/a/7IyC4) a small chunk of what I see when I print x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume once you load the `.npy`, the item (`np.load(path_to_use).item()`) looks similar to this;

```
{'user_c': 'id_003', 'user_a': 'id_001', 'user_b': 'id_002'}
```

So, if you need to come up with a DataFrame like below using above dictionary;

```
  user_name user_id
0    user_c  id_003
1    user_a  id_001
2    user_b  id_002
```

You can use;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(x.item().iteritems()), columns=['user_name','user_id'])
```

---

If you have a list of dictionaries like below;

```
users = [{'u_name': 'user_a', 'u_id': 'id_001'}, {'u_name': 'user_b', 'u_id': 'id_002'}]
```

You can simply use

```
df = pd.DataFrame(users)
```

To come up with a DataFrame similar to;

```
     u_id  u_name
0  id_001  user_a
1  id_002  user_b
```

---

Seems like you have a dictionary similar to this;

```
data = {
    'Center': [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]],
    'Vpeak': [1.1, 2.2],
    'ID': ['id_001', 'id_002']
}
```

In this case, you can simply use;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)  # df = pd.DataFrame(file_dict.item()) in your case
```

To come up with a DataFrame similar to;

```
    Center          ID      Vpeak
0   [0.1, 0.2, 0.3] id_001  1.1
1   [0.4, 0.5, 0.6] id_002  2.2
```

---

If you have `ndarray` within the dict, do some preprocessing similar to below; and use it to create the df;

```
for key in data:
    if isinstance(data[key], np.ndarray):
        data[key] = data[key].tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Okay, so your first suggestion works except that I'm wondering if there's a way to make all of the keys column headers without specifying each individually? Because there are a lot of them and it defaults to putting each as a row. Thank you so much!

Comment: With just file_dict = np.load(path_to_use) and then df = pd.DataFrame(list(file_dict.item().iteritems())), what I get is [this.](http://imgur.com/a/nVjNE)

Comment: @Rebecca, can you share the output of `file_dict.item()` instead of the df?

Comment: It's huge and proprietary but [here's](http://imgur.com/a/7IyC4) a glimpse of it. I've been messing with it a bit and I think one of the problems is that some of the keys like 'Center' have values of which are actually lists of coordinates that pandas doesn't understand how to parse. I've found some slow ways to index and add them but there's got to be a better way...

Comment: @Rebecca please refer to the updated answer, hope that might help

Comment: It's very strange -- when I do that I get the following error: "Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional"

Comment: @Rebecca ah, that's because you have np.array within the dict, instead of having python lists.. refer to updated answer

Comment: Getting really close! Thank you so much for all of your help! Seems like the only problem now is that that the key 'Center' creates a list that is way longer than the others. How can I split it into three 1D arrays (one x, one y, one z) within this preprocessing?

Comment: Actually this is just a problem specific to how my file was saved. You've answered my question! Thanks!